# How can I get Facebook's open graph scraper to successfully parse my single-page website hosted via GitHub Pages?

Tags: html, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph, github-pages

One of my friend set up a simple one-page website and asked me to help to integrate open graph metadata so that sharing on Facebook provides a better user experience.

Unfortunately, Facebook doesn't recognize some values and Facebook's URL Debugger doesn't really help, cause it shows stuff from the registrar by default and fails with the error message `Error parsing input URL, no data was cached, or no data was scraped.` when I click on the **Fetch new scrape information** button. Also, when I click on **See exactly what our scraper sees for your URL**, I get the following error **Document returned no data**.

The URL is: http://know-your-limits.com/. The registrar is Gandi and the site is hosted on GitHub. The DNS configuration is as follows:

```
dig know-your-limits.com +nostats +nocomments +nocmd

; <<>> DiG 9.8.3-P1 <<>> know-your-limits.com +nostats +nocomments +nocmd
;; global options: +cmd
;know-your-limits.com.      IN  A
know-your-limits.com.   10771   IN  A   192.30.252.153
```

1. Is there something I could do to fix this on something I have control on (ie registrat configuration, GitHub repository update, HTML update) as opposed to stuff I don't have control on (ie GitHub web server)?
2. Do you think it is a bug with GitHub hosting?

Comment: Requesting that URL using a tool such as http://web-sniffer.net/, it shows that it redirects to `/`, which is not only technically wrong, but even if a correct absolute URL was used, would be the same URL again, so you’d get a redirect loop. Since this does not happen in a normal browser, it is most likely the usual cause of issues such as this once again: Some plugin or server-side rule that tries to block “bots”, and does a poor job at it.

Comment: Good point. Unfortunately, I don't think I have control over this beyond DNS configuration since GitHub is dealing with HTTP responses. Another weird thing is that when using the Facebook debugger with http://know-your-limits.com/index.html, it considers the og:url to be '/' even though it's set as `index.html` in the HTML. So Facebook asumptions about URL seems to make the matter ever worse. Sad face.

Comment: `http://know-your-limits.com/index.html` also issues an invalid `Location` header, with a value of `/index.html`. (Again, when requested with the aforementioned tool – and it is likely that the FB scraper gets the same response.)

Comment: I just reproduced that via curl but then, running it again, I didn't. So it seems random. But again, that's GitHub server responding. I'll let the question sit here in case some GitHub support people are spying the `github-pages` tag. Thanks guys.

Comment: Doesn't this question belong on [webapps.stackexchange.com](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/)?